# Find the initial speed of M given the following conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Two men, M and N started walking towards each other simultaneously from two places F and G, which are 50 km apart.They meet after 5 hrs. After their meeting , M reduced his speed by 1 kmph and N increased his speed by 1 kmph.They arrived at G and F respectively at the same time.Find the initial speed of M?

My Approach:

Let $S_M$ and $S_N$ be the speed of M and N
When the move towards each other Their meeting point will be at d=$50$

Relative speed$= S_M+S_N$

$t=5$

$$50=(S_M+S_N)\cdot5 \quad \implies S_M+S_N=10$$

When they move towards the other destination i.e M moves towards G and N moves towards F. Therefore,at that point their time is equal

So,

$5. S_M/(?)=5 . S_N/(?)$

(?) means I am confused here how to calculate their relative velocity.

Am I doing right till here? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Since they arrive at $F$ and $G$, respectively, at the same time we have:
$$\frac{5S_M}{S_N+1}=\frac{5S_N}{S_M-1}$$

Since the point where they met is $5S_M$ km apart from $F$ and $5S_N$ km apart from $G$.

Since $S_M+S_N=10$ we have
\begin{align}
\frac{5S_M}{(10-S_M)+1}&=\frac{5(10-S_M)}{S_M-1}
\end{align}

Comment: How u Calculate  SN+1 and SM-1.Please elborate?

Comment: First, we are supposing the speeds are mesured in km/h, also we know that "After their meeting , M reduced his speed by 1 kmph and N increased his speed by 1 kmph" which means that the speed of M when he walk towards G is exactly $1$ less that the speed before the meeting, which is $S_M-1$. On the other hand, N is now walking with a speed $1$ greater than before, which is $S_N+1$.

Comment: I Know that why Sn+1 and Sm+1 is there.I need to know more specifically Why you divided 5Sm/Sn+1 Why It should not be Sm-1 there Because we are talking about M Distance and M Speed

Comment: I am considering $$\text{speed}=\frac{\text{distance}}{\text{time}}$$, then $$\text{distance}=\text{speed}\cdot\text{time}$$ Now, the distance from the point where the two men meets to F is $(S_M)\cdot (5)=5S_M$, so the time needed for N to travel this distance walking at $S_N+1$ km/h is $$\text{time}_N=\frac{\text{distance}}{\text{speed}}=\frac{5S_M}{S_N+1}$$, similarly the distance that M must travel is $(S_N)\cdot(5)=5S_N$ and the time that he needs is $$\text{time}_M=\frac{\text{distance}}{\text{speed}}=\frac{5S_N}{S_M-1}$$